# cin / getline in one line in console app

Tags: c++, cin, getline

So i have the next problem, i tried to imput two strings, one can be null other must be . I tried with

```
 cin>> param1>>param2
```

Note that param1 cannot be null param 2 can be null. Does not work when param2 is null.

Next i tried with `getline(cin,param1)` and `getline(cin,param2)`
this works but i need to give params in two lines in console app.

I need to read from console param1, param2 in one single line.
Please note that i'm beginner with this programming language.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you say "So i have the next problem" in every single one of your questions? How is that relevant to any of the questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that does not work, because `cin` then waits for the second parameter.
You'd need to use `getline()` and parse the string manually.

One possibility is to do this:

```
string params, param1, param2;
getline(cin, params);
istringstream str(params);
str >> param1 >> param2;
```

Note that the param2 will be empty then if only one param passed, because the stringstream ends (cin does not end).

That being said, this will still not work for cases like
`"parameter 1 with spaces" "parameter 2 with spaces"`
because istream simply splits on spaces and does not handle quotes.

Normally when application needs parameters, `argc` and `argv` arguments of `main()` are used to get them from the application command line (where the quoting also works)

Answer (score 2):

`cin` is for reading, so stream direction is inverse:

```
cin >> param1 >> param2;
```

Comment: I modified, sorry, i was in a hurry

Answer (score 1):

`cin` is a model of a `std::istream`. With any istream the result of `stream >> x` is a reference to the `istream` itself.

The `istream` contains some flags to indicate the success or failure of the previous operations.

`istream` is also convertible to `bool`. The value of the bool will be `true` if the previous operations were successful and false otherwise (for any reason).

Thus, if we wish, we can chain not just the `>>` operations but other checks too.

This might be a little advanced but I think you'll find it interesting.
You can compile and run this program as is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>


struct success_marker
{
    success_marker(bool& b)
    : _bool_to_mark(std::addressof(b))
    {}

    void mark(bool value) const {
        *_bool_to_mark = value;
    }
    bool* _bool_to_mark;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, success_marker marker)
{
    marker.mark(bool(is));
    return is;
}

success_marker mark_success(bool& b) {
    return success_marker(b);
}

void test(const std::string& test_name, std::istream& input)
{
    bool have_a = false, have_b = false;
    std::string a, b;

    input >> std::quoted(a) >> mark_success(have_a) >> std::quoted(b) >> mark_success(have_b);

    std::cout << test_name << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::string(test_name.length(), '=') << std::endl;
    std::cout << have_a << " : " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << have_b << " : " << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::istringstream input("\"we have an a but no b\"");
    test("just a", input);

    // reset any error state so the stream can be re-used
    // for another test
    input.clear();

    // put new data in the stream
    input.str("\"the cat sat on\" \"the splendid mat\"");
    // test again
    test("both a and b", input);

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
just a
======
1 : we have an a but no b
0 :

both a and b
============
1 : the cat sat on
1 : the splendid mat
```